# Visual Studio 2015 Community to Visual Studio 2017 Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am testing Visual Studio 2017 Pro.  During this I loaded a VS 2015 Community project and tried to create a unit test.  I was unable to see the "Create Unit Tests" menu when clicking on a public sub in the context menu.  However, when I create a new project in 2017 Pro I am able to.

Anyone know if it is possible or how to make this happen so that I can create unit test in a project that was created in VS 2015 community and loaded in VS 2017 Pro? The VS 2017 Pro is Version 15.01 (26403.7) release, the framework is version 4.6.01055.

The project is in VB.net.

Comment: And now I installed the unit test boilerplate and cannot even run VS 2017 because it returns an unknown error.

Comment: Well, test failed.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to let them know about it.  Or just wait for a month or three to give other customers a chance to test it.